# How can access all of the images in Instagram slides (posts with multiple images or videos) with Instaloader?

Tags: python, instagram, instaloader

I'm using **Instaloader** to develop an Instagram scraper bot. here's part of my code that is getting images url from install by each profile:

```
def scrapImageAddresses(PROFILE):
    print(PROFILE)
    L = Instaloader()
    L.login('####', "####")
    profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)
    imageList = []
    for post in profile.get_posts():
        imageList.append({
            'url': post.url,
            'media_id': post.mediaid
        })
    return imageList
```

But for slides like [this](https://www.instagram.com/p/CH3R89pAG7B/), it only gets the **first** image of the post. I want **all** images in the post.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all sidecar nodes (slides) in every post and add the corresponding url to the list:

```
def scrapImageAddresses(PROFILE):
    print(PROFILE)
    L = Instaloader()
    L.login('####', "####")
    profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)
    imageList = []
    for post in profile.get_posts():
        for slide in post.get_sidecar_nodes():
            imageList.append({
                'url': slide.video_url if slide.is_video else slide.display_url,
                'media_id': post.mediaid
            })
    return imageList
```

Documentation: [`Instagram Structures — Instaloader documentation`](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html#instaloader.Post.get_sidecar_nodes)